# How can I read png file as binary (0 and 1) in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I can read a `bmp` file as binary `( imread('char/C.bmp') => ans=[1 1 0 0 0] )` but when it comes to `png` files I cannot `( imread('char/C.png') => ans=[9 7 7 7 7 2] )`.
What should I do to convert binary form?

Comment: Why don't you read it in uint8 format and then threshold it to get a binary image. I am not familiar with the bmp binary read but if bmp contains values 0-255 then there is some thresholding involved, maybe indirectly. What range of intensity do the images you are reading contain?

Comment: Png image is already in 8-bit depth.

Comment: 8-bit depth is **not** the same as 'binary'. Is the PNG a *monochrome* bitmap? If not, do what @Eypros says: if the value is greater than a certain threshold (> 127 for an evenly distributed grayscale image), then `1` else `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `im2bw` to convert your image to a binary image.